# parse HTML into objects

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following html I am trying to parse into objects in Java using jsoup.

I'm trying to traverse the elements and extract all "Class" as objects to generate timetable data. Each "Class" has a time, location, lecturer and description and so on, but that is not the issue.
All elements are of class `tt_details`. Each day does not have a specific parent to child relationship, however I can extract the days involved using `Elements dayNames = content.getElementsByClass("tt_day");`

Each day can have a different number of "Classes" per day as you can see Monday has 3 "Classes" and tuesday has, so a normal loop structure won't work. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_day'>Mon</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_timeslot'>11:00 - 13:00
        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Mon)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tt_detail'>Internet of Things<br/>E1010 - MAC Lab <br/></div>
    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Loftus, M</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_timeslot'>13:00 - 14:00
        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Mon)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tt_detail'>Computer Systems & Networking<br/>A0004 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (132) <br/></div>
    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Lang, D</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_timeslot'>16:00 - 18:00
        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Mon)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tt_detail'>Intro.to Programming L8<br/>D2005 - Computer Laboratory (32) <br/></div>
    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Kinsella,V</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_day'>Tue</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_timeslot'>09:00 - 10:00
        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tt_detail'>Mathematics 2<br/>A0004 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (132) <br/></div>
    <div class='tt_lecturer'>O'Regan,D</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_timeslot'>10:00 - 11:00
        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tt_detail'>Mathematics 2<br/>E0017 - Tiered Classroom (106) <br/></div>
    <div class='tt_lecturer'>O'Regan,D</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_timeslot'>11:00 - 12:00
        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tt_detail'>Intro to Programming<br/>A0006 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (152) <br/></div>
    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Kinsella,V</div>
</div>
<div class='tt_details'>
    <div class='tt_timeslot'>16:00 - 17:00
        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>
    </div>
    <div class='tt_detail'>Computer Systems & Networking<br/>A0006 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (152) <br/></div>
    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Lang, D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery with your project? This would make it much, much easier.

Comment: html is like an XML so you can create Object with xml annotation and use Mashal and unMarshal

Comment: Its a scraper to feed an android app, so I'm not using any jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could help:

```
String html = ""
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_day'>Mon</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_timeslot'>11:00 - 13:00"
        +"        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Mon)</div>"
        +"    </div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_detail'>Internet of Things<br/>E1010 - MAC Lab <br/></div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Loftus, M</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_timeslot'>13:00 - 14:00"
        +"        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Mon)</div>"
        +"    </div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_detail'>Computer Systems & Networking<br/>A0004 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (132) <br/></div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Lang, D</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_timeslot'>16:00 - 18:00"
        +"        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Mon)</div>"
        +"    </div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_detail'>Intro.to Programming L8<br/>D2005 - Computer Laboratory (32) <br/></div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Kinsella,V</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_day'>Tue</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_timeslot'>09:00 - 10:00"
        +"        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>"
        +"    </div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_detail'>Mathematics 2<br/>A0004 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (132) <br/></div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_lecturer'>O'Regan,D</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_timeslot'>10:00 - 11:00"
        +"        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>"
        +"    </div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_detail'>Mathematics 2<br/>E0017 - Tiered Classroom (106) <br/></div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_lecturer'>O'Regan,D</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_timeslot'>11:00 - 12:00"
        +"        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>"
        +"    </div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_detail'>Intro to Programming<br/>A0006 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (152) <br/></div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Kinsella,V</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"<div class='tt_details'>"
        +"    <div class='tt_timeslot'>16:00 - 17:00"
        +"        <div class='tt_day_small'> (Tue)</div>"
        +"    </div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_detail'>Computer Systems & Networking<br/>A0006 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (152) <br/></div>"
        +"    <div class='tt_lecturer'>Lang, D</div>"
        +"</div>"
        ;
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements courseEls = doc.select("div.tt_details:not(:has(div.tt_day))");
class Course{
    public Course(String day, String time, String lecturer, String subject) {
        super();
        this.day = day;
        this.time = time;
        this.lecturer = lecturer;
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public String day;
    public String time;
    public String lecturer;
    public String subject;

    public String toString(){
        return day + " : "+ time +" : "+ lecturer + " : "+ subject;
    }
}
Map<String,List<Course>> coursesByDay = new HashMap<>();
for (Element courseEl : courseEls){
    Element timeSlotEl = courseEl.select(".tt_timeslot").first();
    String timeSlotStr = timeSlotEl.ownText();
    String dayStr = timeSlotEl.select(".tt_day_small").first().text().trim().replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    String detailStr = courseEl.select(".tt_detail").first().text();
    String lecturerStr = courseEl.select(".tt_lecturer").first().text();

    Course course = new Course(dayStr, timeSlotStr, lecturerStr, detailStr);
    List<Course> courses = coursesByDay.get(dayStr);
    if (courses == null){
        courses = new ArrayList<>();
        coursesByDay.put(dayStr, courses);
    }
    courses.add(course);
}

//get all courses on Tue
List<Course> courses = coursesByDay.get("Tue");
for (Course c : courses){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

This creates a map with courses by day. So the map key is the day and it contains a list of Course objects.

Some remarks about this:

- I use a custom Object to hold the course infos
- I use the selector `div.tt_details:not(:has(div.tt_day))` to get only the course divs, leaving out the day divs. This is possible because the info about the day is repeated within the course div.
- CSS selectors are used to get the details.
- Note the difference between ownText() and text(). This is used to only get the time info without the day.
- The Map is filled with its contents dynamically.

Comment: I'm unable to iterate through the set of elements. The line `for (Element courseEl : courseEls){` is giving a compile error saying `Unknown class: courselEls`

Comment: courseEls should be of class Elements, which implements the List interface. You should be able to iterate over this. Did I or you make a typo?

Comment: Apologies, it was caused by a typeo

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
static final String[] DETAILS = { "tt_timeslot", "tt_day_small", "tt_detail", "tt_lecturer" };
```

and

```
     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
     String day = null;
     for (Element e : doc.select("div.tt_details")) {
         Elements days = e.select("div.tt_day");
         if (days.size() > 0) {
             day = days.get(0).text();
             System.out.printf("    *** %s ***%n", day);
         } else {
             System.out.printf("        --------%n");
             for (String cls : DETAILS) {
                 Elements elements = e.select("div." + cls);
                 if (elements.size() > 0)
                     System.out.printf("%24s : %s%n", cls, elements.get(0).text());
             }
         }
     }
```

result

```
*** Mon ***
    --------
         tt_timeslot : 11:00 - 13:00 (Mon)
        tt_day_small : (Mon)
           tt_detail : Internet of Things E1010 - MAC Lab
         tt_lecturer : Loftus, M
    --------
         tt_timeslot : 13:00 - 14:00 (Mon)
        tt_day_small : (Mon)
           tt_detail : Computer Systems & Networking A0004 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (132)
         tt_lecturer : Lang, D
    --------
         tt_timeslot : 16:00 - 18:00 (Mon)
        tt_day_small : (Mon)
           tt_detail : Intro.to Programming L8 D2005 - Computer Laboratory (32)
         tt_lecturer : Kinsella,V
*** Tue ***
    --------
         tt_timeslot : 09:00 - 10:00 (Tue)
        tt_day_small : (Tue)
           tt_detail : Mathematics 2 A0004 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (132)
         tt_lecturer : O'Regan,D
    --------
         tt_timeslot : 10:00 - 11:00 (Tue)
        tt_day_small : (Tue)
           tt_detail : Mathematics 2 E0017 - Tiered Classroom (106)
         tt_lecturer : O'Regan,D
    --------
         tt_timeslot : 11:00 - 12:00 (Tue)
        tt_day_small : (Tue)
           tt_detail : Intro to Programming A0006 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (152)
         tt_lecturer : Kinsella,V
    --------
         tt_timeslot : 16:00 - 17:00 (Tue)
        tt_day_small : (Tue)
           tt_detail : Computer Systems & Networking A0006 - Tiered Lecture Theatre (152)
         tt_lecturer : Lang, D
```

Comment: Getting elements with certain classes with CSS should better be done with `element.select(".classname")`, because if an element carries multiple classes you can't really be sure about the ordering of the class names. with the dot operator you can easily handel this. Also you can concatenate like this: `el.select(".className1.className2")`. Still I like your simple approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

If this is from HTML source of an online page then you can use selenium for such purposes, for this you have to import selenium jars.

My suggestion -

```
String datentime = driver.findElement(By.className("tt_timeslot")).getText();
```

if you have same name of the elements, then use unique id's or css selectors or xpaths.

Comment: The only information I have to work with is what's posted in the HTML, there is no more id's or css selectors to work with

Comment: you can create xpaths by using existing <div>elements as locations. for example -  //div/div[@class='tt_day']